# Blueprism - Select Item

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have a list box which a user needs to click, then select a value from the dropdowns. I am trying to use Blueprism to select a value from the list by using the 'Select Item' action in a navigate stage. I have identified the on screen element as a list box. However when I run the stage I get the following error.

Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Navigate Stage 'Update Payment Method' on page 'Clone Policy' - Select Item is not implemented for active accessibility elements with role 'DropList'

I want to be able to pull the payment method into a data item from my process, pass it into this object and then select an item.

Please see screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of application is that? Is it a web-app or desktop?

Comment: It's a desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the small screenshot the application seems to be old (VB6 is my guess). Blue Prism, or any automation tool for the matter, may have trouble interacting with legacy apps. I would try these solutions, in this order:

1. Attempt to spy the element using Win32 or Active Accessibility mode (or the UI mode if you have BP v6+)
2. Use Application Navigator (dropdown button next to the Identify button) to see if you can spy the list items themselves
3. Check how reliable would it be to use keystrokes on the dropdown. I can imagine pressing the "DOWN" key for value change and reading the dropdown value using a reader stage for validation
4. Worst case scenario, you could use region/list region and OCR the dropdown list. It should be reliable enough, but I still prefer to not go this way unless there are no other options.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to spy the element using the Active Accessibility mode. This is what I used in my question above. Is there a reason why select item is not working for me?

Comment: @E_McAndrew Unfortunately, there may not be a better reason than the element simply not supporting the "Select Item" action BP is trying to invoke on the element. It can happen with the old apps, even if the element is recognised as DropDown.

Comment: Thanks I was able to find a shortcut which highlights the field. I could then read the value when it was highlighted. However, this has brought me on to a new issue. Which I have posted a new question on.

Answer (score 0):

Some times instead of text and value , Select Position works where you need to pass the number For example: You want to choose B in a List which contains A , B , C and D. Then in select position - just pass 2 .Let me know if its helpful.